# Finding cell with zero in a range and delete the next cell macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I need some guidance on a problem I'm having. I created a macro that deletes cell contents if it equals zero. What I want to accomplish is also add the next cell on the right be deleted together. For example if cell "B38" equals 0 then delete contents of cell and the contents of "C38". Below is what I have that deletes just the cell that equals zero.

```
Sub FindZeros()
Dim z As Range

    Range("B38:B63").Select
    For Each z In Selection
        If z.Value = 0 Then z.delete
     Next z

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Resize(), also when deleting loop backwards.

```
Sub FindZeros()
Dim z As Long

    For z = 63 to 38 step -1
        If activesheet.cells(z,2).Value = 0 Then activesheet.cells(z,2).Resize(1,2).delete
     Next z

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. Also, I wanted to add that I was getting compile error until I declared z As Integer, and after that it worked perfectly.